# Second partial derivatives at (0, 0) for the function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

For the function $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^{4}y^{2}}{x^{4}+y^{2}},x^{2}+y^{2}\neq0\\
0,x^{2}+y^{2}=0
\end{cases}$$

I need to find $f_{x}^{\prime}(0,0)$ and $f_{y}^{\prime}(0,0)$

I don't know the answer but I was told it is not $0$ and $0$. However, I don't understand why. First, $f(0, 0) = 0$ so it's sort if constant and if you differentiate a constant, it is $0$. Second, even if I apply the regular technique, there will always be a fraction with only $x$'s and $y$'s in both the numerator and denominator and but in this case I don't know what to do because it is $0/0$.

How to find $f_{x}^{\prime}(0,0)$ and $f_{y}^{\prime}(0,0)$?

Comment: Let $f(x)=x$ in 2D. At the origin the functional value is zero but derivative is $1$.

Comment: @PNDas Ok, I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the following definition twice

$$
f_x(x,y)=\lim_{h\to 0}{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)\over h}
$$

$$
f_y(x,y)=\lim_{h\to 0}{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)\over h}
$$

Comment: Actually OP wants $f_x'$

Comment: And what does $f'_x(x,y)$ mean for a multivariate function?

Comment: What I am saying is $f_x'$ may not be $f_{xx}$.Because $f'$ may not be $f_x$

Comment: I understand, but how should we define $f'_x$ to apply to this question? Is not the notation $f'$ reserved only for single-variate functions?

Comment: I was talking about total derivatives but I got your point.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz But if apply the regular technique I will get the same and still I won't be able to use $(0, 0)$ because I will get $0/0$.